# Failed to open the SAP GUI for Java: No compatible installation of SAP GUI for Java was found

Tags: java, eclipse, sap-gui

Building Eclipse I want for SAP GUI on macOS Ventura 13.3 M1 Pro. I set up SAPGUI 7.70rev6 aarc64 and Eclipse Software via https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/latest.

SAP GUI working correctly. But I'll use Eclipse for ABAP developing. This error is getting when I launch (F8) ABAP program on Eclipse:

> Failed to open the SAP GUI for Java: No compatible installation of SAP GUI for Java was found. Minimum version is 074000000000. Required architecture is aarch64. Please install a compatible SAP GUI version.
>
> Installed versions: /Applications/SAP Clients/SAPGIJl 7.70rev6/SAPGUl 7.70rev6.app (077000040600, x86_64)
>
> [image]

I tried [this solution (remove and reinstall SAP GUI then restart Eclipse/ADT)](https://answers.sap.com/questions/13282095/eclipseadt-cannot-find-sapgui-for-java-on-linux-sy.html) but it doesn't work. I have not found how to clear all SAP GUI directory. Only, I did uninstall & reinstall the SAP GUI.

Also,

Before, I was getting the JavaFX error [same like here](https://community.neptune-software.com/topics/abap/blogs/how-to-setup--eclipse-to-work-with--s-a-p--gui-for--java):

> The system reqirements are not met.
>
> Could not find: javafx.properties in: /Users/.../.p2/pool/plugins/org.ecIipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.macosx.x86_64_17.0.0.v20211012-1O59/jre/lib
>
> Your Java Virtual Machine seems not to support JavaFX, required to run the SAP GUI for Java 7.50 rev 12.
>
> Please make sure you provide a valid path to the Java FX modules during gui installation.
>
> See the SAP GUI for Java documentation, chapter 5.1 for in depth information about Java FX and modules.

I solved it out update with Java JDK8 & SDK21 and adding parameters line to eclipse.ini. Now, I'm only getting the error on the top image.

> Failed to open the SAP GUI for Java: No compatible installation of SAP GUI for Java was found. Minimum version is 074000000000. Required architecture is aarch64. Please install a compatible SAP GUI version.
> Installed versions:
> /Applications/SAP Clients/SAPGUI 7.70rev6/SAPGUI 7.70rev6.app (077000040600, x86_64)

Help me please, How can I solve that?

Comment: GUI 770 for Java doens't seem to support aarch64. But in the download center I can see a MacOS on ARM64 version for GUI 780. You should try installing that one.

Comment: What Dirk Trilsbeek says. aarch64 means ARM 64 bit alias Apple silicon (M1/M2), but you have x86 64 bit, running via Rosetta 2.

Comment: I have edited your question to include the essence from external links (otherwise the question will have no interest for future visitors if the external links disappear).​ Please review and make sure it's okay for you.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments: M1 uses a new architecture, and while GUI 770 can run on an M1 chip, eclipse probably needs native support instead of an emulation, therefore you need to switch to a GUI version that natively supports ARM64 apple silicon. SAP GUI 7.80 should (and does, as the comments suggest) work.